# Display image with absolute path in Flex Air

Tags: apache-flex, air, path

I have very simple Flex Air application where I'd like to load image from documents directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" creationComplete="init(event)">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            protected function init(event:FlexEvent):void {
                image.source = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath('image.jpg').nativePath;
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:BitmapImage id="image"/>

</s:WindowedApplication>
```

The problem is that Flex Air doesn't know how to handle native (absolute) path.

Looks very easy, but I don't know how to solve it...

Comment: Why don't you use the url then? `File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath('image.jpg').url` Or does that not work either?

Comment: Yes! That's exactly what I was missing. @RIAstar, could you please post your response as an answer, and I would accept it. Thank you!

Comment: Done. Wasn't 100% certain, which is why I didn't answer at first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a URL (or a ByteArray) to load an non-embedded image, so use the File's [url](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html#url) property instead of its `nativePath`.

```
image.source = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath('image.jpg').url;
```

Comment: I found it very useful to wrap File.urls in URLRequests when you have special charcters like "+" in your filename. The reason for this is that File encodes urls and replaces "+" with "%2B". When taken as image.source the url will be encoded again and "%2B" will be falsly interpreted as %252B. `image.source = new URLRequest(File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath('image.jpg').url ) ` will solve this issue.